# how to get the value of checkboxselected in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my java script

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function (e) {
                var cnt = $("input[name='technologies']:checked").length;
                var cnt1 = $("input[name='technologies']:checked").val();
                alert(cnt1);

                if (cnt < 3) {
                    for (i = 0; i < $("input[name='technologies']:checked").length; i++) {
                      var cnt2 = cnt1.val(i);
                      alert(cnt2)
                    }
                    alert(cnt);
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                else


                    alert('Well Done!!!!');
            });
        });

    </script>
```

My html code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="technologies" value="JavaScript" />JavaScript <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="technologies" value="Prototype" /> Prototype<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="technologies" value="Dojo" /> Dojo<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="technologies" value="Mootools" /> Mootools <br /></div></td></tr></table>
```

I need the values of checked in forloop statement. Unable to get the checked values, i am getting only one checked value

Answer (score 1):

You're confused as to what returns an array and what doesn't.

```
var elms = $("input[name='technologies']:checked")
for (i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    var cnt2 = elms[i].val();
    alert(cnt2)
}
```

`elms` is an array, whose elements can by accessed by index.

Comment: iam getting error while going elms[i].val() .  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Please use value insteat of val() so replace  elms[i].val() with elms[i].value